# Communicate with two mysql databases on different server

Tags: php, mysql, database, server

I have a two websites with their mysql databases. I want to communicate with 2nd website's database and fetch results from there.

For Example:

- Website A and Database DA are on the first server
- Website B and Database DB are on the second server

I want website B fetch results from Database DA or vice-versa.
What are the correct ways to achieve this? How can I communicate with different database which is on different server?

Comment: Nothing yet. I'm a newbie and I don't know how to achieve this so I'm searching for a good and optimize answer.

Comment: When you create the database connection you can use whatever server you want as host.
Example: mysql_connect(YOUR_HOST, USER, PASS);

Comment: Slightly improved the formatting and pointed out that the two websites are on different servers